# How can we connect artificial intelligence with cognitive psychology?

Tags: comparison, philosophy, cognitive-science

On page 62 of [Artificial Intelligence and Cognitive Psychology Applications, Models](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d16d/2c064e6be92bfde86ff56fb57f32172673be.pdf) (2010), Gabriella Daróczy writes

> Psychology is one of the basic sciences of artificial intelligence (AI). The founder of the psychology is Wilhelm Wundt (1832-1920), who engaged in empirical methods, and was interested in the thinking processes during his scientific work.
>
> Psychology had two main leading schools: behaviourism, and cognitivism.
>
> Behaviourism: Refused the theory of the mental processes, and insisted to study the resulted action or the stimulus strictly objective. The representatives of this theory have been decreasing with time.
>
> Cognitive psychology: The brain is an information processing device. Artificial Intelligence supports also this idea, and the first picture illustrates the information processing model of the brain

How can we connect artificial intelligence with cognitive psychology? Can we integrate psychology into AI?

For example, in the context of human-computer interaction, could we have an AI software/application that makes use of phycology-based ideas/theories?

Answer (score 6):

AI is already connected with cognitive psychology - there are dozens of AIs right this minute attempting to predict things like which Facebook posts you will like, and which ads you are most likely to click on. In other words, they are trying to predict how you think.

For more detailed info on this AI/cognitive science connection, there is some suggested reading on [AITopics.org](http://aitopics.org/topic/cognitive-science), such as [Paul Thagard's summary of cognitive science](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/cognitive-science/).